# Unexpected `await` inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

This block of code is causing the titled eslint rule to error. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the iteration dependency but I'm not quite seeing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (let i = 0; i < areaRes.hits.hits.length && i < MAX_PAGE_LIMIT; i += 1) {
  const record = areaRes.hits.hits[i];
  const snapshot = await listings.forBoundary(record, filter, listingType,
    status, roleId, roleType);
  areaResponseArr.push({ ...snapshot });
}
```

Comment: Use `Promise.all(array.map())`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Your title seems to refer to one thing, your text to another, and separately there isn't (nearly) enough information in the question for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could push the promises in your loop and use `await` outside of the loop, like:

```
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < areaRes.hits.hits.length && i < MAX_PAGE_LIMIT; i += 1) {
  const record = areaRes.hits.hits[i];
  promises.push(listings.forBoundary(record, filter, listingType, status, roleId, roleType));
}
const areaResponseArr = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: I was actually trying to do something akin to what @SLaks mentioned above and got too caught up in it. Forgot I could just do this. :P Thanks!! How do I mark this as the answer I used?